# Safari3 and Safari4 side by side

Tags: safari

I've just read about the release of [Safari4 (beta)](http://www.apple.com/safari/download/) and its much improved Javascript engine. 
I was planning to start playing with it, but I am wondering if anybody knows if both Safary 3 and Safari 4 can be run side by side.

Answer (score 1):

You could run Safari 3 and use the [nightly builds of Webkit](http://nightly.webkit.org/) to test the new engine. You'd be still missing the new features like Cover Flow and Top Sites though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/)

> Safari normally use the Web Kit
>   framework found inside Mac OS X to
>   render web pages and execute
>   javascript. This means that if you
>   preserve an old version of Safari to
>   run it on a newer version of Mac OS,
>   it will use the newer Web Kit found in
>   the system and you will get the same
>   results as with the newer version.

However, the link has some stand alone versions that you can install.

There's also [this](http://michelf.com/weblog/2005/multi-safari/) which shows how to create your own stand alone version.

Comment: It sounds interesting, but the original post seems extremely old (2005) and there is no date indication on the other page. If that solution really works then I assume they will post pretty soon a standalone Safari4 version.

Answer (score 0):

[Beatnik Pad has a quick tutorial that shows how running Safari 4 Beta and Safari 3 side by side](http://www.beatnikpad.com/archives/2009/02/24/safari4-safari3) can be accomplished.